# Angular 6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to migrate the angular app from 5 to 6 version.
The app is running well but if I do some changes in my code
after page reloading, I am facing a weird error:

```
core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/secure/dashboard/member-index/member-index.module.ngfactory.js (member-index.component.ts:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:56
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4062)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/secure/dashboard/member-index/member-index.module.ngfactory.js (member-index.component.ts:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:56
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4062)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

Did someone face this error? Why this error appears after code changing?

**UPD**

I was using `ng serve --aol` to run my app.
If I use `ng serve` the error disappears

Comment: what changes...?

Comment: Do you have a .call in member-index.component.ts ? What is the pine 33 in that file ?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Whats @ (member-index.component.ts:33) ?\

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski whatever changes, even add one space.

Comment: @DrNio no, I haven't

Comment: @Antoniossss https://monosnap.com/file/B0xivuw02ZwKJxBaMsyrEXNv1JophS

Comment: too hard to edit?

Comment: Show your project  tree - do you have some temporary directories like `dll`, `compiled` or something? May be you have some old compiled code... remove it and try compile again

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski I guess it makes sense. The problem in a compiler. When I remove --aol from my starting script command, my error is disappear. What does it mean?

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm sure it is error of compiler. it is not about my code

Comment: @DmitryGrinko if you are so sure about the cause, then why posting here and asking for help?

Comment: I've same problem, did you manage to fix it?? Removing aot helped me temporarily

Comment: Same problem here! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Issue FIXED by angular-cli team, you just need to update your `"webpack": "^4.15.1"`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11129) Good luck.

> This was my earlier answer.

**This is an open-label:`comp: devkit/build-angular` issue in angular-cli.**

Yes, you are right in the `ng serve` you don't see the error. Even I faced the same error while developing my application, I did end my `ng serve` and tried again, it worked and the `ng build --prod` is also successful. Please refer to the below-provided link, you will get to know more on this.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11129

Comment: What if I have this issue in Angular 9, but don't have `webpack` in `package.json`? Should I add it? If so, which version?

Comment: @Halfist, have you fixed it. i am also facing the same issue

Comment: @AnantaPrasad, I don't have this issue in Angular 11 anymore, but I don't really remember how this was fixed back in the days.

Answer (score 13):

I think it happens when you make changes to module imports during run time.

**Run the application again using** `ng serve` and it fixed the issue for me.

*It may also occur when you try to use components of lazy loaded modules in other modules before the lazy module getting loaded or such similar scenarios.*