# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined from webpackAsyncContext (Webpack error)

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am getting the following error for certain pages on my website. It is related to Webpack.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Why is this error happening?

The stack trace doesn't show any of my code. It is happening in Webpack code:

```
function webpackAsyncContext(e) {
    if (!n.o(r, e))
        return Promise.resolve().then((function() {
            var t = new Error("Cannot find module '" + e + "'");
            throw t.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
            t
        }
        ));
    var t = r[e]
      , o = t[0];
    return Promise.all(t.slice(1).map(n.e)).then((function() {
        return n(o) // <---- ERROR HAPPENING HERE
    }
    ))
}
```

UPDATE 1:

Error stacktrace is as follows:

```
main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:1644 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (main-client.js?v=HBU…HNYpSTrLMew46Jy0:20)
    at main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:38946
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39643)
    at Object.onInvoke (main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7197)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39643)
    at Zone.run (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39537)
    at main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:40017
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39656)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7189)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39656)
    at resolvePromise (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39975)
    at resolvePromise (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39952)
    at main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:40018
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39656)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7189)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39656)
    at Zone.runTask (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39568)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39754)
defaultErrorLogger  @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:1644
ErrorHandler.handleError    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:1663
next    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7472
i   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:6748
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:27250
SafeSubscriber.next @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:27224
Subscriber._next    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:27204
Subscriber.next @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:27196
Subject.next    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:36275
EventEmitter.emit   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:6735
(anonymous) @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7207
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39643
Zone.run    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39537
NgZone.runOutsideAngular    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7232
onHandleError   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YpSTrLMew46Jy0:7206
ZoneDelegate.handleError    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39645
Zone.runGuarded @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39550
_loop_1 @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39890
Zone.__load_patch.n.microtaskDrainDone  @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39896
drainMicroTaskQueue @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39760
Promise.then (async)        
scheduleMicroTask   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39741
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39652
onScheduleTask  @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39617
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39648
Zone.scheduleTask   @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39586
Zone.scheduleMicroTask  @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39592
scheduleResolveOrReject @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:40011
resolvePromise  @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39971
(anonymous) @   main-client.js?v=HBU…pSTrLMew46Jy0:39928
webpackJsonpCallback    @   main-client.js?v=HBU…YHNYpSTrLMew46Jy0:5
(anonymous) @   0.js:formatted:1
```

UPDATE 2:

Error stacktrace after upgrading from Angular 7.2 to 9.1. Still the same issue.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:24)
    at Module.280 (3.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:24)
    at main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:57250
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58417)
    at Object.onInvoke (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:13800)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58417)
    at Zone.run (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58227)
    at main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58839
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58440)
    at resolvePromise (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58793)
    at resolvePromise (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58761)
    at main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58840
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58440)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:13791)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58440)
    at Zone.runTask (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58267)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (main-client.js?v=En9ov5sOxlQIVwZOduy8ehlKv7mPkjk-C6t7aJXanQY:formatted:58572)
```

UPDATE 3:

It has something to do with lazy loading. When I changed it to default loading (importing modules directly), it worked. (I have also updated hrefs and replaced them with routerLink.)

Right now, it has default loading.

Comment: I don't get the error -- however, with the HTTPS page, my browser asks if I want to install an app -- but not if I visit HTTP. So maybe that's where the problem is? Or perhaps post the portion of the code which is outputting this error.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak It is now happening in both HTTP and HTTPS, so I have updated my question and put in the portion of the code where the error is happening.

Comment: Could be due to gstatic cookies. At least this is what I get in chrome as a warning. I get no errors on the provided url though. Have you fixed it?

Comment: I didn't get any error. Try to hard reload from your browser or use different browser, may be cache issue

Comment: I tried it on different computers and browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and they all fail. (The page should show post content, and not just a header bar.) I have updated the post with the stack trace.

Comment: I think you could provide a bit more context?

Comment: Hello @JonasArcangel, if you haven't done it yet could you remove the node_modules folder completely and do a fresh npm install?

Comment: Yes I just tried again now but still the same result.

Comment: @JonasArcangel Its working on my system. I followed all steps mentioned on your github and I am able walk through application. If you need we can discuss on chat.

Comment: Tried to walk through some pages and no errors like this. One thing I wonder. Why do you use `href` over `routerLink`? SPA works like a very heavy static website reloading the page each navigation. Also to ease your debugging you could use sourcemaps

Comment: @GouravGarg It works locally for me too. There are portions of code that is Git ignored (like node_modules) and something may have gone wrong there.

Comment: Might be a challenge with timezones. So no one else is getting the same error from Console? (I use Chrome DevTools.) Just another note, the site has server side rendering. SSR is ok and renders fine. When it does the Angular rendering, that's when the error happens.

Comment: I'm seeing that the error is when it is trying to load module ./modules/forum/forum.module.ngfactory

Comment: Can you put webpack.config.js ?

Comment: Can you please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375181/angular-6-typeerror-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined

Comment: My Angular and Webpack versions are ahead of what is in that post. I'm now trying to upgrade to Angular 9 and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Performed the upgrade to Angular version 9.1 but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you share a step-by-step from the source code to reproduce your situation? I got an error and had to `npm install ngrx-data`. Apart from that I could not replicate your exact error. Please check that and let me know, so I can investigate better andtry to elaborate an answer.

Comment: Which browser and version of it are you trying with? And did you make sure you cleared your cache before?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce locally, unfortunately. I'm trying to investigate this issue by going through transpiled javascript from the production server. I'm using Chrome, but I see the same issue in Firefox, Edge, and Safari, on my laptop, desktop, and mobile. I clear the cache before trying.

Comment: I have updated the navigation to use routerLink instead of href. It seems to have exposed module errors. There seems to be something wrong with forum module, but I'm not able to figure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to write an answer because it's too long as a comment. I suspect that this is because of the service worker.

I can reproduce your issue by navigating to the food link, or another link after having the page rendered once. I then have a blank page with the same error.

If before navigating to another page I unregister the service worker, the navigation works successfully.

To test and disable the service worker, open chrome's debugger, go to the **Application tab**, then click **Service Workers** on the left, and then click **unregister** on the right.

You'll need to activate source maps to identify the exact error, but I tracked it down to  the line 279 (once formatted) of the file `3.js`.

```
ForumSubforumFormComponent
    }()
      , F = o(294) // <=== error here
      , C = function() {
        function Topic(t) {
            this.contentItem = t,
```

When service worker is registered, F is a function

```
console.log(F)
ƒ hooks(){return a.apply(null,arguments)}
```

When the service worker is registered, o(294) throws an error, probably because it's not included in webpack.

When looking at the requested files in the network tab, it looks like there are 2 different version of the `main-client.js` file that are requested (depending on wether the page has been requested by the browser or the service worker).

This might be the cause of the issue.

Also service workers can only be registered using HTTPS, which would explain why the problem did not occur before using http. Testing http on your website is not possible anymore, since there is a 307 redirection to https.

**Note** As indicated in one of the comments, the navigation is a bit weird on your website.. it refreshes the whole page everytime you navigate. Also, angular universal does not seem to always render

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. It may have worked for server side rendering? I've turned it off and redeployed to test if it will fix it, but I'm still getting the issue. This may be why you are getting problems with Angular Universal. I'm not sure how it is possible to have two versions of main-client.js. I only see 1 in the filesystem.

Comment: I also think that it works on the server-side so that may be why some are not seeing any issues?

Comment: I have updated the navigation to use routerLink instead of href. It seems to have exposed module errors. There seems to be something wrong with forum module, but I'm not able to figure what it is.

Comment: The issue is related to lazy loading. When I imported the module directly, it works. I have updated the question above.

Comment: Not really. It works with default loading, so for the moment I'm leaving it at that. I don't need the modules to be lazy loaded, but eventually I'll come back to figuring out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the terms and conditions you reference the AuthService and PageService.

I don't find where they are declared. This one i.e. could miss the AuthService:
https://github.com/jasebanico/banicocms/blob/master/src/Banico.Web/ClientApp/app/shared/shared.module.ts

Or this one the PageService:
https://github.com/jasebanico/banicocms/blob/master/src/Banico.Web/ClientApp/app/plugins/modules/page/page.module.ts

Alternatively you could use 
@Injectable with `providedIn`

Does this help?

Otherwise I find it a bit hard to debug.
So I'd suggest using `ng new` to create a new project structure (you can add options to ignore the creation of the git repo) and merge your code into. This way you don't have to deal with adapting webpack and so on when doing upgrades.